# How to get a restated tcolorbox to appear in the list of tcolorboxes

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox, cleveref

A definition is being restated. The MWE lists the original version in the list of definitions. I would like the restated version also to appear. (It's ok if the list entries are the same.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%---This is where the PACKAGE must be.
\tcbuselibrary{%Begin load libraries for tcolorbox  
        skins,%
            }%End load libraries for tcolorbox      
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}] 
\usepackage{cleveref}
%$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Begin new tcolorbox - COMMANDS must be after cleveref.
\newcounter{dft}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= dft,
number within=chapter,
list inside= dft,%creates the list under tcblistof
crefname={definition}{definitions},
Crefname={Definition}{Definitions},
]%endForReferences
{efinition}%
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},%
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{\textbf{#2}}},%%Used to include mytitle in the ``number''
title=DEFINITION \thetcbcounter \, #2,%
nameref=#2,%
list entry={DEFINITION ~\thetcbcounter ~ #2},%
#1,%Required for references.
}%
%=======Begin To restate an already stated definition STURM after YASMAR
\newtcolorbox%
{efinitionRphr}%
[3][]%
{%
detach title,%This prevents the top from being the color of the frame
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},%This prevents the top from being the color of the frame
enhanced,%
arc=0.2mm,%
colback= yellow,%
colframe= black,%
coltitle=black,%
title= DEFINITION ~\ref{#2}~\nameref{#2},%
list entry={Definition~\thetcbcounter},
#1%
}%
%=======End To restate an already stated definition STURM after YASMAR
%$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ End new tcolorbox
\begin{document}
\chapter{Original}
 \begin{efinition}[label={dft:1-1}]{Maximum}
  An input whose output is larger than the outputs for nearby inputs
\end{efinition}
\chapter{Restated}
\begin{efinitionRphr}[label={dft:1-1a}]{dft:1-1}{~}
The biggest of all
\end{efinitionRphr}
\tcblistof[\chapter]{dft}{List of Definitions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to your custom `tcolorbox` to appear in *List of Definitions*, you have to reference it. This is the resulting code after some changes

```
\newtcolorbox[%
            use counter= dft,
            number within=chapter,
            list inside= dft,
            crefname={definition}{definitions}
]
    {efinitionRphr}
            [2][] {%
            detach title,
            before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
            enhanced,
            nameref={#2},
            arc=0.2mm,
            colback= yellow,
            colframe= black,
            coltitle=black,
            title=DEFINITION~\ref{#2}~\nameref{#2},
            list entry={DEFINITION~\ref{#2}~\nameref{#2}},
            #1%
    }
```

Note that the number of parameters of your `tcb` are now just 2, so the **Restarted** box has to be changed like this

```
\chapter{Restated}
\begin{efinitionRphr}[label={dft:1-1a}]{dft:1-1}
    The biggest of all
\end{efinitionRphr}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked even without `usecounter`,  `number within` and `crefname`. It didn't even occur to me that `list inside` should be necessary again. (Which goes to show that I do not understand much.) Thanks.